# Physical interpretation of $\iiint (∇\cdot\vec E)\mbox{d} V$

Tags: electrostatics, gauss-law, calculus

1. Can anybody explain the physical interpretation of [Gauss's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_law) $$\iiint (\nabla\cdot \vec E)~\mbox{d}V~=~\frac{Q}{\epsilon_0}?  $$
2. Also, how is the differential form of Gauss's law obtained from the integral form?
3. How can volume multiplied by a gradient equals flux through a closed surface?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/74788/2451

Answer (score 1):

It's just the total amount of divergence within the region, or the total electric flux out of its boundary. Perhaps you are more familiar with the differential form:

$$\nabla\cdot\vec E =\frac{q}{\epsilon_0}$$